# Access specific element from array in zf2

Tags: php, properties, zend-framework2

I have an array `$pname` in view which I accessed from controller, when I write `print_r($pname);` output is:

> Admin\Model\Provinces Object ( [id] => 4 [p_name] => Khyber Pakhtunkhwa [inputFilter:protected] => )

I need to show **Khyber Pakhtunkhwa** in view:

I tried echo `$pname['p_name']`; but it show me an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Admin\Model\Provinces as array in C:...

So how could I do this, i.e., access specific data from an array.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `$pname` is **NOT** an array, it is an object of type `Admin\Model\Provinces` (as you can clearly see in the output of your print call).

To access propeties of simple php objects you can sometimes use array notation as you do (read more on this [here on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php)), but in this case it isn't allowed on this type of object hence the error message.

You can access the object properties in your object probably by using the arrow notation (in case [a magic getter](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) is implemented) or using the getters provided in the class `Admin\Model\Provinces`.

This is basic PHP stuff I suggest you get more familiar with PHP before you start working in a complex framework like Zend-Framework 2.